# QTreeView clear selection

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I want to clear the treeView selection, I use 
`static_cast<QTreeView*>(mContext)->selectionModel()->clear();`,  `static_cast<QTreeView*>(mContext)` being the tree I'm talking about, however a secondary light blue selection remain, how can I remove the selection entirely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To clear the selection use `clearSelection`

```
static_cast<QTreeView*>(mContext)->selectionModel()->clearSelection();
```